# JDK, Eclipse, and Path Variable

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to get Eclipse set up for Android development, but when I started Eclipse, I got an error message saying that it could not located the JDK bin folder in the PATH variable. So I followed some instructions and went to set the PATH variable, but found that it had been set by AMD. However, since that was stored under "Path" and not "PATH" I thought it might be case-sensitive (not much experience with the environment variables), and created the new one. But that overwrote the Path variable set by AMD, and I got a message telling me that the Catalyst Monitoring program had stopped working.

So how can I restore the Path variable to what it was before I changed it, and what is the proper way to set up Eclipse?

Comment: You didn't tell us what it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least complicated thing to do is reinstall your video driver (catalyst control panel) - this should restore your PATH environment variable to having the value for the `Catalyst Monitoring` program.

Then when you're updating the PATH variable, you add:

```
;<path to JDK bin folder>
```

to the end of the variable. This will this to the path. The path variable is a semi-colon delimited list.

Comment: Unless someone has an installed copy of the Catalyst Control Panel that they can allow you to easily crib the original value from

Comment: That did the trick--I didn't completely clean out the old driver.

And I'm also getting an error message from Eclipse saying it can't load the JNI shared library at the designated path. I've made sure I have the 64-bit version of everything Java and Eclipse installed, but no luck.